# django manytomany field add dynamically

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have two regular models in Django:

```
class One(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Two(models.Model):
    first_field = models.ForeignKey(One)
    ones = models.ManyToManyField(CouponType, related_name='ones_two')
```

I'd like to do dynamically something like that:

```
item_one = One()
item = Two()
item.ones.add(item_one)
```

This works for Foreign Key:

```
field = Two._meta.get_field('first_field')
kwargs = {field_name: value}
field_value = field.rel.model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)[0]
setattr(Two, 'first_field', field_value)
```

How to do same for ManyToMany field?

Comment: What error do you get when doing the same for m2m?

Comment: Object is not iterable

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking about how to add data to many to many list

```
your_object.ones.add(what_you_want_to_add)
```